# "Cleanest" approach towards automatically generating `val` assignment expressions in Scala 2.11.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

It seems as though `sbt` wants real `lazy val`s declared in the lowest scope to do anything physically.

If I make a function `def m100kProjects()` and it really does instantiate and return `100` new `Project`s, `sbt` will do nothing without me assigning them to the scope of the function itself... ie project on the scope, NOT enumerable of project.

```
def mk100Projects = { }

val 100Projects = mk100Projects() // right now, sbt is quiet.

val project0 = 100Projects(0) // 1 project is materialized!
val project1 = 100Projects(1) // 2 materialized!
```

What I would really like is to be able to instantiate projects on some other owner/scope in whatever way, so that either a)  the result of instantiation is what I have come to expect, or b ) the instantiation magically happens in my world using implicits or else. Please let me know you thoughts